# USDZ File Black on Older Devices and Normal Map artefacts

Tags: scenekit, blender, ios12, pbr, usdz

I'm stuck creating USDZ files. I've issues with older devices, basically anything older than the iPhone X, displaying items with artefacts resulting from normal maps and other issues whereby the item appears entirely black.

iPhone X and iPad on ios 12 and 12.1 betas run fine with no normal maps: 
[image: iPhone X and iPad on ios 12 and 12.1 betas run fine:]

iPhone 7 iOS 12 non beta with no normal maps:
[image: iPhone 7 iOS 12 non beta]

When I use normal maps I get the following issue on older devices: 
[image: Normal maps causing shininess issue]

You can download the raw files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13w4fFTr6EQSUyQeEryxQWp0FcPN-84Ci?usp=sharing

Any help is extremely appreciated <3